# H264 RTP packet parsing

Tags: video, rtp, h.264

I am looking for source code of RTP Payload Format for H.264 Video according to RFC(3984).
It would be great if someone can point out it.

Also I am looking for wireshark plugin which can show me the packet decoding of h264.

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Above link gives me a "404 Not Found" error. This may fix it (for now). http://github.com/erlyvideo/ertsp/blob/master/src/rtp_server.erl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with FFMpeg's source code (under LGPL); the [rtp_h264.c](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=history;f=libavformat/rtp_h264.c;hb=9cad7e219377de4b466e8858286de23df3615b86) contains the code that parse H.264 RTP frame. You should have a solid knowledge of the RFC 3984 to follow the code...

Answer (score 1):

More up-to date answer: look at project [moonlight](https://github.com/moonlight-stream) on github. Moonlight is a NVidia real time streaming client, it has many useful network APIs, much easier to digest than ffpmeg. For your specific problem: [processing RTP payload](https://github.com/moonlight-stream/moonlight-common-c/blob/f5ae5df5d0/src/VideoDepacketizer.c)