# Capturing stream

Tags: java, h.264, capture, rtp

I am using Java and need to save audio/video stream to a local file.

So far I managed to send RTSP commands and get the stream saved.

However, each RTP pack (DynamicRTP-Type-96) does hold a header and a payload. The payload is holding a NAL header and the actual NAL.

What should be actually saved to the resulting video file from this inbound stream ?

Are you aware of Java libs which can each packet parsing ?

Answer (score 1):

Packets do not normally make a decodable stream as they are, without modification (esp. depacketization). Instead, the payload has certain structure, which is defined by respective document or specification. Typical payloads are:

- [RFC 6184 (3984) - RTP Payload Format for H.264 Video](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184)
- [RFC 6416 (3016) - RTP Payload Format for MPEG-4 Audio/Visual Streams](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6416)

It would perhaps be helpful to check earlier Qs out, which are very much related:

- [H264 RTP packet parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225688/h264-rtp-packet-parsing)
- [Why RTP/RTSP meddle with my H.264 NALs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580069/why-rtp-rtsp-meddle-with-my-h-264-nals)

Comment: please have a looks at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665217/how-to-process-raw-udp-packets-so-that-they-can-be-decoded-by-a-decoder-filter-i, Cipi's reply. When start bit is set and end bit is not set, do I have to insert the NAL prefix as well, or only the NAL unit byte followed by the actual VIDEO FRAGMENT DATA ?